# If we use False or True with 0 or 1 in the dictionary for keys. what will happen?

Tags: python, dictionary

I was working on a simple example on dictionaries in Python, I realized that there was a problem and I didn't understand it.

```py
paris = {
    1: 'apple',
    'orange': [2, 3, 4],
    True: False,
    12: 'True',
}
print(paris)
```

Why my output for this code is:

`{1: False, 'orange': [2, 3, 4], 12: 'True'}` and not `{1: 'apple', 'orange': [2, 3, 4], True:False, 12: 'True'}`

The value for the key `1` is `False`, not `'apple'`, as I expected. If I use another number for key number 1, I get the expected output.

Comment: Because `1` and `True` hash to the same value. In general booleans are a subtype of int in Python.

Comment: use the same type for the key's of the dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to understand:

1. In Python the boolean data type is a sub class of int data type. That means True is 1 and False is 0.
   So, True is converted to 1.
2. In Python, keys in dictionary has to be unique. So when you assign a value corresponding to the same key (as True is 1 now), it will update the value of dictionary.

So data: 1:'apple' and True: False will result to 1:False

Answer (score 2):

The error is because you have both the keys 1 and True, which resolves to 1. And since in Python dictionaries, the keys have to be unique, the `1:apple` gets overwritten by `True: False`, which gets displayed as `1: False`.

Putting boolean values in a dictionary along with other types of variables isn't a great idea.